# Is it acceptable to install games on a work smartphone

Tags: phone

Unlike with computers a lot of work provided phones are completely unlocked and work just like a regular phone.

Actual guidance on what you can and can't do with work phones is also often light on the ground.

Generally, is it considered acceptable or not to install apps such as games on work provided smartphones (for use outside work hours)?

Comment: You don't care about "generally", you care about what will actually happen in your company.

Comment: Why not ask? Then you know for sure the policy of the company

Comment: No, don't do it. Keep your personal life separate from your work life.

Comment: I've always played games on my work laptop during lunch

Comment: Would you install Grinder or other Social Apps?

Comment: This question assumes that installing an app on a phone is harmless. With the number of apps that track the user or use up phone resources even while not being in use, that assumption can be questioned. Remember that any app that is free is selling information about you to someone else.

Comment: Vote to close - company specific and pure opinion bait.

Comment: Silly question, why couldn't you buy your own smartphone and then install games to your heart's content ? If you cannot afford own smartphone then its perhaps time to find another company ;)

Comment: this is an **excellent question**.  OP wants to know if **generally** it is acceptable.  OP, the answer is a firm NO, it is very usually very much NOT acceptable.

Comment: @PhilipKendall , no, the OP wants to know generally; what is typical.  As it says in the title and text.

Comment: *"Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department"* this question has utterly no connection to the "OP's manager or HR".  OP may not even have a job.

Comment: Yeah...really bizzare to see it shut for this reason. I have a job. But no wish to play games on a company smartphone (which I don't have). Its just a general question given I've noticed a lot of people do have these and increasingly use them for personal reasons.

Answer (score 2):

> Unlike with computers a lot of work provided phones are completely
> unlocked and work just like a regular phone.
>
> Actual guidance on what you can and can't do with work phones is also
> often light on the ground.
>
> Generally, is it considered acceptable or not to install apps such as
> games on work provided smartphones (for use outside work hours)?

Keep in mind that the hardware, and the software are owned and controlled by the company. In some cases the IT department has the ability to wipe the phone at any time. I have know people that lost personal files on their phone because they failed to understand this.

The reason why they gave you the phone is so they can contact you at any time, and you have an ability to do specific work functions even when not sitting in front of a company computer. Assume that IT can get a list of all non-standard applications. Assume they can read every file on the phone, and that nothing personal is safe from IT.

The reason you wanted a company phone, versus using a phone you own, is so that you can separate your life from work. Put any game you like on your phone, only install required applications on the work phone.

Keeping the work phone clean also minimizes the chances that you install a virus onto the phone. You wouldn't want to be the source of something that steals company information.

Check the documents you signed when they gave you the phone regarding your rights and responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

> Generally, is it considered acceptable

No, generally they just expect you to use it purely for work.

Answer (score 1):

No, don't do it someone will notice that you installed extra apps other than your work apps. It would be a much bigger risk for you. If you still want to then hide those apps during work hours. But I would prefer to install those kinds of apps on my personal phone rather than my work phone.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your companies policy but as long as what you install isn't morally or ethically questionable it shouldn't be a problem.

It all boils down to whether the company expect you to have only one phone or whether you are expected to have a separate work and private phone.

Most companies I worked for companies expect you to carry your work phone 24/7 and so it's reasonable that you configure your phone to handle most aspects of your private life as well. Otherwise it's hard to tell what exactly is "work related": For example I have the United Airline app on my phone and sometimes I use it for work travel and sometimes I use it for private travel. And yes, playing Candy Crush while you are commuting on a train is perfectly acceptable as well.